# as3 conditional compiling with flascc

Tags: actionscript-3, mxmlc, conditional-compilation, flascc

I had as3 project with custom flex-config.xml and conditional compiling directives for mxmlc like this:

```
<define append="true">
  <name>CONFIG::DEBUG</name>
  <value>true</value>
</define>
<define append="true">
  <name>CONFIG::RELEASE</name>
  <value>false</value>
</define>
```

How I can to do that with flascc g++?

Comment: The only way i found is generate abc first via asc

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/docs/Reference.html) for FlasCC's gcc says

```
-fllvm-llc-opt= Pass an argument through to the final invocation of llc (LLVM-IR->ABC codegen).
```

while running `$FLASCC_HOME/usr/bin/llc --help` shows

```
-ascopt=<asc options> - Extra options to pass to ASC when compiling ActionScript
```

Finally, running `java -jar $FLASCC_HOME/sdk/usr/lib/asc2.jar` shows that one of the arguments it takes is

```
[-config <ns::name=value>]
```

So it seems like we should be able to do this:

`gcc ... -fllvm-llc-opt="-ascopt=-config CONFIG::RELEASE=true"`

Unfortunately, while the flag does actually make it to asc.jar (!), it appears to be getting passed as *one argument* (rather than two), so it errors out.  The space required by `-config` is screwing things up.

The [workaround](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1117606?tstart=0) is to pass the two pieces of the arg separately:

`gcc ... -fllvm-llc-opt=-ascopt=-config -fllvm-llc-opt=-ascopt=CONFIG::RELEASE=true`

Comment: btw, if what you're after is actually conditional compilation *in C* then you can always do `-DFOO=BAR`.